# How to find line with special string in richtextbox and save

Tags: vb.net

First, I am new learner vb and my English language not good, i hope you can understand my question. Thanks

**I have richtextbox**

- abc
- def
- ghj
- abc
- 123

**And 4 checkbox**

- abc
- def
- ghj
- 123

**1 Button Save**

++++

If i check checkbox1 ( abc ), richtextbox show only line have string "abc" ( in this demo, it show only 2 line have "abc"

And if i click save, dialog will open for save new file have 2 line string "abc" to pc

If i check checkbox2 ( def ), richtextbox show only line have string "def"

And if i click save, dialog will open for save new file have 1 line string "def" to pc

Checkbox3 + 4 same 1 and 2.

I hope someone can help me this issue, thank you so much.

Comment: [https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: I'm afraid this site is not a code writing service. It is a place where you can ask for help with code you have written. If you have written some code to do what you want, edit your post to include it and explain what happens when you run it.

Comment: Code! Include your code! Read [ask] to learn how to ask questions properly here! And [mcve] to learn what code to include!

Answer (score 0):

to erase all the text in the textbox but the checkbox text

```
 For Each line In RichTextBox1.Lines
        If line <> CheckBox1.Text Then
            RichTextBox1.Text = RichTextBox1.Text.Replace(line.ToString, "")
        End If
    Next
```

and to write to file...

```
My.Computer.FileSystem.WriteAllText("path", TextBox1.Text, False)
```

you can change "path" with path from savefiledialog

```
Dim saveFileDialog1 As New SaveFileDialog()
If saveFileDialog1.ShowDialog() = DialogResult.OK Then
    My.Computer.FileSystem.WriteAllText(saveFileDialog1.FileName, TextBox1.Text, False)
End If
```

Good Luck!